# Sharepoint - Provisioning xsl Style Files

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to provision a .xsl file with custom styles to be applied to a `Content Query Web Part` in SP 2007 MOSS. I want to deploy it in a feature.
So far any attempt has failed as I cannot retrieve my .xsl in the Style Library.

```
 <!-- Feature.xml -->
 <ElementManifests>
     <ElementManifest Location="Elements.xml" />
     <ElementFile Location="Test.xsl" />
 </ElementManifests>



 <!-- Elements.xml -->
 <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
   <Module Name="Test" Url="Style Library/XSL Style Sheets" Path="" RootWebOnly="FALSE">
     <File Url="Test.xsl" Type="GhostableInLibrary"/>
   </Module>
 </Elements>
```

My solution structure:

[image]

There are no errors in the log files. For what I've seen on the web, this should work but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the second folder in your URL path. What you need to do is set the URL attribute in your file element.

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">     
   <Module Name="Test" Url="Style Library" RootWebOnly="FALSE">      
            <File Url="XSL Style Sheets/Test.xsl" Path="Test.xsl" Type="GhostableInLibrary"/>    
   </Module>  
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a slash before the Style Library bit. Also, this'll only work in a Publishing Site.

Comment: Not necessarily, if the publishing features are turned on the style library would be created, or sharepoint would create the path automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching `RootWebOnly` from `FALSE` to `TRUE`.

(Be sure you are actually activating this Feature in the Root Web)